# Python - From DST-adjusted local time to UTC

Tags: python, timezone, utc, dst, pytz

A specific bank has branches in all major cities in the world. They all open at 10:00 AM local time. If within a timezone that uses DST, then of course the local opening time also follows the DST-adjusted time. So how do I go from the local time to the utc time.

What I need is a function `to_utc(localdt, tz)` like this:

Arguments:

- localdt: localtime, as naive datetime object, DST-adjusted
- tz: timezone in the TZ-format, e.g. 'Europe/Berlin'

Returns:

- datetime object, in UTC, timezone-aware

EDIT:

The biggest challenge is to detect whether the local time is in a period with DST, which also means that it is DST adjusted.

For 'Europe/Berlin' which has +1 DST in the summer:

- Jan 1st 10:00 => Jan 1st 9:00 UTC
- July 1st 10:00 => July 1st 8:00 UTC

For 'Africa/Lagos' which has no DST:

- Jan 1st 10:00 => Jan 1st 9:00 UTC
- July 1st 10:00 => July 1st 9:00 UTC

Comment: Pitfall: 27 March 2011 at 01:00, clocks were set forward to 02:00. So the interval between 01:00 and 02:00 is invalid. 
30 October 2011 at 01:00, clocks will be set back to 00:00. So the interval between 00:00 and 01:00 is ambiguous.

Comment: `pytz` describes that DST transitions don't work for any timezone that has one. If a package built specifically to help with timezones doesn't support that, then it's too much work for you to do correctly yourself. You'll have to settle for almost right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/), and in particular its [localize method](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic):

```
import pytz
import datetime as dt

def to_utc(localdt,tz):
    timezone=pytz.timezone(tz)
    utc=pytz.utc
    return timezone.localize(localdt).astimezone(utc)

if __name__=='__main__':
    for tz in ('Europe/Berlin','Africa/Lagos'):
        for date in (dt.datetime(2011,1,1,10,0,0),
                 dt.datetime(2011,7,1,10,0,0),
                 ):
            print('{tz:15} {l} --> {u}'.format(
                tz=tz,
                l=date.strftime('%b %d %H:%M'),
                u=to_utc(date,tz).strftime('%b %d %H:%M %Z')))
```

yields

```
Europe/Berlin   Jan 01 10:00 --> Jan 01 09:00 UTC
Europe/Berlin   Jul 01 10:00 --> Jul 01 08:00 UTC
Africa/Lagos    Jan 01 10:00 --> Jan 01 09:00 UTC
Africa/Lagos    Jul 01 10:00 --> Jul 01 09:00 UTC
```

Comment: note: some local times are ambiguous. Though it is unlikely that a bank opens at a time during DST transition; you might use `is_dst=None` parameter for `.localize()` to assert that.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, tzinfo, timedelta

class GMT1(tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return timedelta(hours=1)
    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)
    def tzname(self,dt):
        return "Europe/Prague"
year, month, day = 2011, 7, 23
dt = datetime(year, month, day, 10)

class UTC(tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)
    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)
    def tzname(self,dt):
        return "UTC"

def utc(localt, tz):
    return localt.replace(tzinfo=tz).astimezone(UTC())

print utc(dt, GMT1())
```

New Version. This does what you want -- takes a naive datetime and a timezone and returns a UTC datetime.

Comment: Your solution fails to solve the main challenge: Automatic handling of DST.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If the `tzinfo` you use has a `timedelta` for DST, it should be automatically handled by `utcnow()`?

Comment: Still not sure how this solves the DST problem. Prague in July should in UTC+2 (including DST). You still return a `timedelta(0)` for the dst in `GMT1`: correct for GMT+1 indeed, but that's not the time zone for "Europe/Prague".